# What are the keyboard shortcuts for navigating Modern UI apps?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-8, modern-ui

Whenever I'm in the Modern UI apps (Photos or Weather or etc), there is always this big 'back' arrow in the upper left hand corner, and instead of using my mouse all the time (on a non touch disply system), how can I use the keyboard to navigate back?

What are the keyboard shortcuts available for navigating the Modern UI applications in Windows 8?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> (also works to go back in explorer, and most browsers).

Answer (score 6):

Here is the complete keyboard shortcut list for Windows 8, [image]

Also available at the official Blog for Windows 8.

[Picture Location.](http://blogs.windows.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/CommunityServer-Blogs-Components-WeblogFiles/00-00-00-53-48-metablogapi/4667.Keyboard_2D00_shortcuts_2D00_for_2D00_Windows_2D00_8_5F00_5756566F.png)

Comment: They should learn to turn off the spell checker's squiggles before taking screen shots. They look so unprofessional.

Comment: @DanD. I hope you are referring to Code Gorillas sitting in Redmond. :)

Comment: Hope no longer, that is indeed so.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>PageDown</kbd> Scroll backward on the Modern Desktop Start screen

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> Cycle backward through open windows

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> Cycle backward through elements in a window or dialog box

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> Cycle backward through elements in a window or dialog box

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> Move backward through tabs

<kbd>Backspace</kbd> Display the previous folder in Windows Explorer  Move up one folder level in Open or Save dialog box

For more keyboard shortcuts you can check out this [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/hyperyash/list-of-windows-8-shortcuts).