# How do I switch between applications in Windows 8?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-8, alt-tab

What are some ways that I can switch between applications in Windows 8, using the keyboard and/or mouse?

Comment: possible duplicate....http://superuser.com/questions/490480/what-are-the-keyboard-shortcuts-for-navigating-modern-ui-apps

Comment: @Moab this is for switching between ANY application(s) in Win8, the other question is for using the keyboard to navigate inside a  Modern UI app.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are a variety of ways to switch between open applications in Windows 8.

- Put the mouse cursor in the very top, left-hand corner, where a small preview of another open program appears. Just keep clicking in the very corner until you reach the open application you want to view.
- Another way to do this with the mouse is to put the mouse cursor in the very top, left-hand corner and then drag the cursor down, while keeping the mouse against the edge of the screen, it will reveal a list of open programs.
- Still another way is to put the mouse cursor in the very upper left-hand corner and, when the small application preview is visible, just click the preview and drag the cursor *right*, it will drag the next application into view.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> still works in Windows 8 - just keep pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> until you see the open application you want.
- <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> also still works in Windows 8 - this will bring up a sidebar with small previews of all the open applications - just press <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> until the app you want shows up.

Comment: I think it should be noted that Windows Key + Tab only works for Metro applications, where Alt + Tab works for all applications (metro and non-metro).

Comment: All of these except alt + tab only seem to be for Metro applications

Answer (score 3):

There are a few else keyboard only ways to switch between applications.

- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> switches to the **next** application and  <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> switches to the **previous** application
- <kbd>Windows Key</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Windows Key</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> ... <kbd>Windows Key</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> switches (or start if it doesn't started) to the pinned application with corresponding number on application bar.
- <kbd>Windows Key</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> - cycle through apps in application bar from left to right. <kbd>Windows Key</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> navigate in opposite order.
- <kbd>Windows Key</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> is a variation of <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. With this keyboard shortcut you do not have to permanently press <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> to scroll through applications.